# Call IBAction of one UIControllerView using another UIViewController's IBAction iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have work on one application and i want to call IBAction of one UIControllerView using another UIControllerView, please help me for how can i implement it.

suppose,
I have two UIViewController named FirstViewContoller and SecondViewController, now i have one IBAction in FirstViewController and another IBAction in SecondViewController, now i want to use SecondViewControllers IBAction on click of FirstViewControllers IBAction.

How can i implement this kind of work.

code snippets will appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the action of the Second vc's outlet? set some value, if you can say that or clear that then it would help.

Comment: Actually i have to put my working code in Second vc and i have button on First vc so i want to use second vc's IBAction when i click on button in First vc.

Comment: Do you want to call the method on the SecondVC or trigger a touch from code. If you need the first one, its pretty easy. All you need to do is SecondVC().myMethod()  but its somewhat unclear if its second case.

Comment: i know this is complex code that i have done. there are many more choice to make it easy but now i have no time to change code thats'y i need to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Delegate

In FirstViewController.h

```
@protocol myDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)changeValue;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) id <myDelegate>delegate;
```

AND SecondViewController.h

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<myDelegate>
```

Again in SecondViewController.m's Outlet action method

```
-(IBAction)mySecondViewControllerOutlet:(id)sender{
  FirstViewController *v = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
   [v.delegate changeValue ];
}
```

Finally in FirstViewController.m

```
 -(void)changeValue{
//Write down the change of code you want to implement
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the situation you explained "*Actually i have to put my working code in Second vc and i have button on First vc so i want to use second vc's IBAction when i click on button in First vc.*"  This is the way you can do it.

```
//this if from FirstVC
@IBAction func doSomething(sender:UIButton!){
let computedThing  = SecondViewController().computeThisThing()
//do what your app needs now
 }
```

Remember on the SecondViewController to have the exact method and return type. 
The SecondViewControllers ibaction will look like this

```
//This is from the Second VC
@IBAction func doSomethingHere(sender:UIButton!){
let computedThing  = computeThisThing()
//do what your app needs now
}

func computeThisThing() ->String {  //or whatever data type is required
//do some work
return "something"
}
```

But i would advise you, to refactor out the common code to a separate class and use it. This makes the design of architecture solid and follows Single Object Single Responsibility Design pattern.

Let me know if this helps. Cheers!